# Determine if R function arguments are unique

Tags: r, arguments

I have function and wish to throw error if arguments are unique

So far I tried:

```
PrintLetters <- function(name, name2, name3){

  if (!unique(args)){
    stop("Enter 1 to 3 unique arguments")
  }

  print(paste(name,name2,name3,sep=" "))
}

PrintLetters("a","b","c")
```

And error results

```
Error in unique.default(args) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

Tried saving args to a vector

```
PrintLetters <- function(name, name2, name3){

  v_args <- c(args)

  if (!unique(v_args)){
    stop("Enter 1 to 3 unique arguments")
  }

  print(paste(name,name2,name3,sep=" "))
}

PrintLetters("a","b","c")
```

New error

```
Error in !unique(v_args) : invalid argument type
```

Please guide

Comment: `any(table(args)>1)` or `length(args) > length(unique(args))`, assuming `args <- c(name,name2,name3)`. (Notice that `unique` is not a yes/no function, it returns the unique members of the vector provided to it. See `unique(c(1,1,2,3))`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
PrintLetters <- function(name, name2 = NULL, name3=NULL){

  args <- unlist(mget(names(formals())))
  if ( anyDuplicated(args) ){
    stop("Enter 1 to 3 unique arguments")
  }

  print(paste(name,name2,name3,sep=" "))
}

PrintLetters("a","b","c")
# [1] "a b c"
PrintLetters("a","b","a")
# Error in PrintLetters("a", "b", "a") : Enter 1 to 3 unique arguments
```

Comment: This will cause an error with less than three arguments: `PrintLetters("a","b")`.  It's better to use `NULL` as an "empty" default: `PrintLetters <- function(name, name2 = NULL, name3 = NULL)`

Comment: @NathanWerth Yes, I will take that into account, i.e set name2 and name3 to NULL

Comment: It's a good point, note that `paste("a","b",NULL)` will return `'a b '` (ending with space), so you'll have to use `trimws` on the result. I also added an `unlist` call because in case of `PrintLetters("a")`, `NULL` was seen as duplicated

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Excellent. I actually ran into this issue and your comment resolved it.